# set file name laravel

Tags: laravel, file

I upload file with this code:

```php
$this->form->file_path = $this->file->store('files/'.$this->file_name.'.pdf', 'public');
```

but cannot set the file name correctly. It stores file under file_name.pdf with a random name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the [store()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files) method, the file name will generated for you. If you want to set the name yourself, you should use the `storeAs` method:

```
$this->file->storeAs('files', $this->file_name.'.pdf', 'public');
```